# How to implement a discrete DC motor controller?

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, dc-motor, embedded, control-system

My question is about implementing a discrete controller. Let's assume the following (case study: *[DC Motor Speed: Digital Controller Design](https://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=MotorSpeed&section=ControlDigital)*):

- I have a DC motor and I want to control its speed, with known parameters (Vin, RPM, shaft inertia, torque, viscous friction coefficient, etc.).
- I want to design a digital controller, for speed control, using a microcontroller. I did the analysis (modeling, frequency response in continuous time, then in discrete time).
- The simulation shows that the PID controller works perfectly in continuous time, the overshoot and stability criteria are met easily.
- When we come to discrete time, the PID does not stabilise the system, and another controller in the Z-domain is found to be:

$$\small\frac{505z^2-790z+305}{z^3+0.82z^2-z-0.82}$$

How to implement the following controller in a real-time system (in hardware or embedded sofware)? What does the Z-transform give in real time?

NB: When transforming this equation to the discrete-time domain, MATLAB returns the following huge equation, which seems impractical:

$$\small\frac{161545250\cdot\left(\frac{-41}{50}\right)^n}{33579}-\frac{40000\cdot-1^n}{9}-\frac{15250\cdot\delta_{n0}}{41}+\frac{500}{91}$$

Comment: Do you mean perhaps z^-2 instead of z^2 ? That would be the notation for the second last measured sample in an FIR/IIR digital filter description.

Comment: @tobalt Matlab returns the equation in terms of z^2, but we can transform it to z^-2, by deviding all the terms by z^2

Comment: My question is answered by Dr Dogan Ibrahim in his book entitled: Microcontroller based applied digital control, to whom it my concern!